# Specify model in Repository with DI PHP

Tags: php, factory, strategy-pattern, ddd-repositories

I have a simple service on PHP with this structure:

```
Controller
  ChannelControllerAPI.php
Service
  ChannelService.php
Model
  Repository
     ChannelRepositoryInterface.php
     RedisChannelRepository.php  // implements ChannelRepositoryInterface
     SqlChannelRepository.php    // implements ChannelRepositoryInterface
     HybridChannelRepository.php // implements ChannelRepositoryInterface
  AbstractChannel.php        
  BusinessChannel.php  // extends AbstractChannel
  UserChannel.php      // extends AbstractChannel
```

And I use DI container to resolve dependencies.

API controller code:

```
class ChannelControllerApi extends  Controller
{
     private $channelService;

     public function __construct(ChannelService $channelService)
     {    
         $this->channelService = $channelService;
     }

     public function getChannelInfo()
     {
         $channelId = $ths->request->Post('channelId');
         $channelType = $ths->request->Post('channelType');
         $result = $channelService->getChannelInfo($channelId, $channelType);

         // return API request
     }
}
```

I get `ChannelService` in Controller Api __construct with DI;

ChannelService code:

```
class ChannelService
    {
         private $channelRepository;

         public function __construct(ChannelRepository $channelRepository)
         {    
             $this->channelRepository = $channelRepository;
         }

         public function getChannelInfo(int $channelId, string $channelType)
         {
             return $channelRepository ->findRules($channelId, $channelType);
         }    
    }
```

`ChannelRepository` code for example `SQLRepository`:

```
use channel/Models/AbstractChannel;

class SqlChannelRepository 
    {
         /**
         * Channel $model (ActiveRecord or DTO Model)
         */
         private $model;

         public function __construct(AbstractChannel $model)
         {    
             $this->model= $model;
         }

         public function find(int $channelId, string $channelType) : Channel
         {
             return $this->model->where('id', $channelId)->where('type', $channelType)->getModel();
         }    
    }
```

Abstract channel model class code:

```
abstract class Channel extends ActiveRecordModel 
{
   protected $tableName = 'channel_business';

   protected $fildmap = [
      'id', 
      'type',
      // ...
   ];
}
```

`BusinessChannel` model class code:

```
class Channel extends AbstractChannel;
{
   protected $tableName = 'channel_business';
}
```

`UserChannel` model class code:

```
class UserChannel extends AbstractChannel;
{
   protected $tableName = 'channel_user';
}
```

I don't want to pass *$channelId* and *$type* to Service or to Repository.

**How?** and in which layer can I pass the right model object to `SqlChannelRepository`?

Where should this logic be placed:

```
if ($requset->Post('type') == 'user') {
    $model = new UserChannel(); 
   // or setting in DI container: app()->container::set('UserChannel');
} elseif ($requset->Post('type') == 'business') {
    $model = new BusinessChannel(); 
} elseif .... { 
   ......
}
```

Please help, which pattern or architect solution (can I use to create right `ChannelModel` by request ($_POST) params and pass it to my repository)?

Sorry for my poor English:)

Comment: You already tagged the `factory` pattern. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Felippe Duarte, can you please show any code example, please? My OOP skills are not so strong))